# Can I connect createBottomTabNavigator to a redux store ? (React Native)

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I have App.js looks like this

```
const TabNavigationStack = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Dashboard: {
      screen: Dashboard,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: () => null,
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon style={{ fontSize: 35, color: tintColor }} name='dashboard' type='MaterialIcons' />
        )
      }
    },
    Home: {
      screen: OrderStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: () => null,
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon style={{ fontSize: 35, color: tintColor }} name='money' type='FontAwesome' />
        )
      }
    },
    Notification: {
      screen: NotificationStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: () => null,
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (

          <IconBadge
            MainElement={

              <Icon style={{ fontSize: 35, color: tintColor }} name='notifications' type='MaterialIcons' />

            }
            IconBadgeStyle={{ zIndex: 1 }}
            BadgeElement={
            <Text style={{ color: '#FFFFFF', fontSize: 10 }}>0</Text>
            
            }
            Hidden={0}
          />

        )
      }
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: Profile,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: () => null,
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon style={{ fontSize: 35, color: tintColor }} name='person' type='Ionicons' />
        )
      }
    },
  }, // router config
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    order: ['Dashboard', 'Home', 'Notification', 'Profile'],
    gesturesEnabled: false,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
      tabBarVisible: true
    },
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: COLOR.PRIMARY_COLOR,
      inactiveTintColor: '#29333D'
    }
  }
)



const CombinedStack = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthStack: AuthStack,
 
    TabNavigationStack: TabNavigationStack,

  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthStack'
  }
)


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Root>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <CombinedStack ref={navigationRef => {
            NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigationRef)
          }
          } />
        </Provider>
      </Root>
    );
  }
}





export default App;
```

Im planning to connect props in create navigator when the user login, I call an api which indicate the number of badge that connected in redux.

I already tried

> const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
> badgeNumber: state.Notification
> });
>
> ```
> const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
>   dispatch: dispatch
> })
>
>
>
> const TabNavigationStack = connect(mapStateToProps)(createBottomTabNavigator)({....
> ```

but the I got error in props.

BTW I'm using react-navigation 2

Comment: not very helpful but im using `screenprops` for a similar case. `navigationOptions` can get a function that passes navigation object. that way you can achieve what you want. Cons: everytime you set screenprops, the whole navigation will re-render.

Comment: @UğurEren can u give me a snippet ?

Comment: You basically pass `screenProps` prop to the navigation, with an object containing data you want to share between all screens. (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/2.x/stack-navigator/#navigator-props). and replace navigationOptions with a function that takes navigation object as param. (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/2.x/stack-navigator/#navigator-props). now you can replace text with what you want. eg 'You have ' + navigation.getScreenProps().`the property you passed to screenProps prop` + ' notifications' -- btw i guess it doesnt work with react navigation 2. nevermind ://

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `IconBadge` component into a separate javascript file ... and connect that component to redux store

```
const AppIconWithBadge = ({ badgeNumber }) = {
  //...
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ badgeNumber: state.Notification });
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppIconWithBadge);
```

- 

```
 tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <AppIconWithBadge style={{ fontSize: 35, color: tintColor }} 
                            name='person' type='Ionicons' />
        )
```